# Why is my SQL statement displayed on web page, along with the correct value?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm currently using a COUNT function in a SQL statement to count the number of rows, and I'm passing this into an HTML template using Flask and Jinja.

Flask app

```
cust_count = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers")
return render_template('index.html', cust_count=cust_count)
```

HTML template

```
<p class="card-text display-1">{{ cust_count }}</p>
```

Output

> [{'COUNT(*)': 3}]

The value of '3' is correct, but why is [{'COUNT(*)' }] also being displayed?

Thanks.

Thanks for the help so far. I added cust_count.fetchone() (not sure if I've done this correctly) but I'm also getting an error message.

Code:

```
cust_count = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS customercount FROM customers")
count = cust_count.fetchone()
return render_template('index.html', cust_count=count)
```

Error:

> File "C:\Users\Brad\Desktop\Final\app.py", line 29, in index
>       cust_count.fetchone()
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

Comment: You should also include more of your code, as there are many `SQL` libraries in python. It is easier for us to help if you include the name of the specific library you are using.

Comment: I'm using SQLite if that helps.

Comment: What TMarks says. My guess is that `db.execute()` returns some kind of a proxy object that you have to call something like `.fetchone()` or `.fetchall()` on in order to get back actuall rows. You should also set an alias (`"SELECT COUNT(*) AS customercount FROM customers"`) for easier retrieval of the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value passed back from `db.execute` is a `ResultProxy`. It's a special object used by SQLite3 (and other SQL libraries).

To access the first item in the list, you would use `cust_count.fetchone()`.

The documentation for that can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I made some amendments (listed above) but I'm now getting an error.

Comment: Hey @Brad, I would suggest you read the error messages carefully in Python, they are exceptionally helpful in determining what went wrong. For instance, the error you have says exactly what the problem is. `fetchone()` won't work in this case. It appears that `cust_count` is *not* a `ResultProxy` but is instead just a list. You can access a lists contents using `cust_count[0]`.

Comment: I would suggest you read this.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp